# Electrical Engineer being autodidact (Without university)

Tags: books

For personal reasons I can't go to the university and I would like learn a lot of electronics oriented to computers. I am not new in the software programming but in all related with the hardware yes, totally new. I searched here to know about recommendations of books of this kind and I have found a lot with very good opinions in Amazon, but I don't know if it's good idea start reading books without an order. What are all the books of the first year of university's electrical engineer course? I have a lot of time to study it. Also, my level of maths is very bad, I have gone a lot of years without studying maths... so another book to have a good understanding of maths?

Comment: Why not just Google you favorite University Electrical Engineering Curriculum, and just follow along?

Comment: @Tyler: Given at posting a totally offtopic question, following along might not be his thing.

Comment: @PlasmaHH i am new here, i thinked the correct place to publish my message was here, sorry. And Tyler i can't go to the university, i would like but i can't...

Comment: Huh you a jailbird?

Comment: @Andyaka Even jailbirds can go to University remotely...

Comment: Regarding calculus: the slewrate (derivative) of a flatline is zero; the slewrate of a ramp is deltaRise/deltaTime and that is used in such formulas as deltaV/deltaT = I/C; the slewrate of a sinwave {Amplitude * sin(2*pi*Frequency*Time)}, written as A*sin(2*pi*F*T) is A * (2*pi*F)*cosine(2*pi*F*T).

Comment: It is economic problem, maybe in the future i can go but at the moment no

Comment: The prestigious MIT have now made most of their courses available free online. The documents cover any required texts and other material. [Start here](https://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no answer to that question.

Each university has their own preferred books, often biased by some alumni connection to the author.

The one we used which is considered by many to be the "bible" of EE is

[Hughes Electrical and Electronic Technology](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2s8MyO6hGENRl9BeTVTeUdRX2VHeGVTSEVOVFpyUQ/edit?pli=1)

As for math. There are numerous teach yourself math books out there. Go visit a good book shop or major library and find the one that personally suits you best.

Comment: Thanks Trevor!! I think with that PDF will be enough for now :) Very very good quality that PDF, thanks.

Comment: @mingett you are welcome. As I said it is the basics of EE, a lot of it you will probably never need but it's there if and when you do. If you are more interested in specifics of circuit and logic design there are other books that are more tailored in detail to those areas, e.g. the book Dirk suggests. If you are serious about using this stuff, you may want to invest in a hardcopy. I still have and occasionally use mine from 40 years ago.. though it's only edition 4 the basics never change.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the latest edition of [Art of Electronics by Horwitz and Hill](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Electronics-Paul-Horowitz/dp/0521370957). I'm a professional EE and that is pretty much all I need on a day to day basis. More specialized info one can find on the Net to supplement it.

Comment: Dirk what field of EE do you work in?

Comment: @hacker804 I do a bit of everything, except power and RF. The bulk of the work is microcontrollers (mostly 32 bit) and analog interface, including precision temperature measurements (sub milliKelvin resolution). Then throw in firmware to drive it all and some physics research, latterly on measurements of ultrasound pulse propagation in gases.